# LC-3 Program to Count occurrences of a char in a string

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am trying to write a LC-3 program that will count the number of occurrences of a char that the user inputs in a string that is hard coded. The part that I am having trouble on is testing if the two characters equal each other, and I am also having trouble moving the next character in the string to test it. 
    ;Program to count occurrences of a char in a string

```
.ORIG   x3000
LD  R3, POSASC  ;Loads R3 with #48
LD  R4, NEGASC
LD  R1, word    ;R1 = word

ADD R6, R6, #5  ;Length of word
GETC            ;Gets the char
OUT         ;Prints the char
ADD     R2, R2, R0  ;Stores the char in R2
;ADD    R2, R2, R4  ;To ascii
AND R0, R0, #0  ;set R0 back to 0
LOOP    
AND     R5, R2, R1  ;check if char is equal
ADD     R1, R1, #1  ;increment to next char in word
ADD R6, R6, #-1 
BRnp    LOOP

ADD R0, R0, R5  ;Set R0 to # of occurrences
OUT         ;Print # of occurrences

HALT
POSASC  .FILL   x0030       ;#48
word    .STRINGZ "hello"    ;word to count occurrences of a char
NEGASC  .FILL   xFFD0       ;#-48
.END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it:

```
    .ORIG   x3000
    LEA     R1, word        ;load address of word
    LD      R4, ascii
    GETc                    ;get char
    OUT                     ;display char
    ADD     R6, R6, #5      ;# of chars in word
    ADD     R2, R0, R2      ;put char in R2

    NOT     R2, R2
    ADD     R2, R2, #1      ;R2 now has 2's complement of char

next    AND     R0, R0, #0      ;clear R0
    LDR     R0, R1, #0      ;get char of word
    ADD     R0, R0, R2      ;add 2's complement to char of word
    BRz     equals
    BRnp    unEqual

equals  ADD     R5, R5, #1      ;add 1 to counter if equal

unEqual ADD     R1, R1, #1      ;move to next letter
    ADD     R6, R6, #-1     ;decrement # of letters in word
    AND     R0, R0, #0      ;clear R0
    ADD     R0, R6, R0      ;test if done
    BRp   next

    ADD     R0, R5, R0      ;put counter in R0
    ADD     R0, R4, R0      ;convert to ascii
    OUT

    HALT
word    .STRINGz "hello"
ascii   .FILL   #48
    .END
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a problem of how to work with strings and arrays.  At the beginning, when you

```
LD R1, word
```

you're going to the memory address that "word" represents and getting a byte.  So at that point R1='h'.

However, later on you're trying to iterate through the string, with

```
ADD R1, R1, #1
```

Now, R1='h'+1='i', which isn't what you intended.  What you've done is incremented the data you've gotten from the memory address, rather than incrementing the address itself.  So instead of starting off with LD, which loads data from memory label, start of with LEA, which loads the effective address of the memory label.  There's one more load instruction that will come in handy also, which is LDR.  This loads data from an address located in a register.  So:

```
LD R1,word     ; "h"
LEA R2,word    ; memory address of word
LDR R3,R2,#0   ; "h"
word: .STRINGZ "hello"
```

Now if you consider that R2=R2+#1 will not increment the data itself, but rather the address, you can see the following:

```
LD R1,word     ; "h"
ADD R1,R1,#1   ; "h"+1="i"
LEA R2,word    ; memory address of word
ADD R2,R2,#1   ; (memory address of word) +1
LDR R3,R2,#0   ; "e"
word: .STRINGZ "hello"
```

Hopefully this will solve your problems.

p.s. You're also assuming registers are initialized to zero.  There's a command on the simulator that randomizes memory prior to start -- this will cause complete havoc to your code, and can happen in real hardware.  Initialize memory before you read it.